# How to show multiple images in a row covering full width always

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to show multiple images(Max 24) of same height and width(154px x 125px) in a box. This has been done easily. But the problem is it leaves blank space when there is not enough space to adjust the last image. I want the images to auto adjust to full width of the box at any screen size. How could I do it ?

```css
.tab-content {
    background-color: #0c1011;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-pane img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.tab-pane a {
    display: block;
}
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/nitingsingh/pen/rJeROm

Comment: how many images you want in a single row?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyNJXN 
add this style for 8 images in a row 
img.img-responsive {
    width: 12.5%;
}

Comment: 10 in desktop, 5 in Tablet and 2 in Mobile.

Comment: @Dexter I would like to maintain the same image width and height always.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: @Dexter Adding bootstrap grid changes the size of image. I don't want the images to shrink or expand at any screen size.

Comment: _I would like to maintain the same image width and height always._ & _10 in desktop, 5 in Tablet and 2 in Mobile._ & _covering full width always_ ? Not possible.

Comment: @VXp Even I also think that this isn't possible through CSS. Adding some jQuery might help. I am going to add 'jQuery' tag in the question.

Comment: You can't do that even with JS/jQuery. You want to keep the dimensions of imgs (you already fail here), always covering row width and changing the number of imgs with @media, of course you can't do that, not logical.

Comment: @VXp So according to you this is an 'Impossible' case ?

Comment: You got that right.

Comment: @hashtagerrors did you check my answer below? If I understand your requirement correctly you don't need JS / JQ. Just CSS (3) is sufficient.

Comment: You need to adjust your requirements, I'd recommend you to avoid maintaining the same w&h of imgs, you can have 2 out of 3 but not 3/3.

Comment: @VXp Sure. I am trying to carry forward Vivek Athalye answer to make some changes programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at flex box in CSS3. 
Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

That should help you. Check this:

```css
body {margin:0} /* addition */

.tab-content {
  background-color: #0c1011;
  padding: 0; /* shorthand */
  margin-bottom: none;
  /*display: block; by default*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tab-pane a {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* shorthand | flex-grow: 1; | flex-shrink: 0; | flex-basis: auto */
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/154/125/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VXp Really? `I want the images to auto adjust to full width of the box at any screen size`. This is what I've read. Have you? There could be a possibility that I've understood it differently than what OP is asking for. But I have certainly read it :P

Comment: Its written in the comments section and I also wrote all three.

Comment: @VivekAthalye This is Helpful.

Comment: @hashtagerrors Glad it helped. You may consider accepting it as answer then.

Comment: @VivekAthalye Sure. But before that I am going to try some more changes. Kindly Wait.

Comment: @hashtagerrors Sure... By all means, try it out. Flexbox is really flexible :D

Comment: @VivekAthalye Is it possible to shrink the image instead of expanding it ? The expanded image takes lot of space some times.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use only `flex-shrink` property (and set `flex-grow: 0;`), then the blank space in container is not distributed among the children elements. In that case you may set it as `flex: 0 1 25%;` and that will show 4 images in a row, irrespective of the screen width. This might shrink the images too much and may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
             .tab-content {
                       width:100%;
                       display: flex;
                       flex-grow:1;
                       flex-shrink:1;
                       justify-content:space-evenly;

                 }

             .img-responsive {
                    max-width:150px;
                    max-height:126px;
             }
```

use max width if  you don't want your image to get bigger and use min-width if you want the image to be atlease 150px you can also use justify-content: space-around ; you should use the flex approach .